# Android GCM turn on Lights

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm doing a project in Android. I can successfully receive push notifications.

How to turn on the lights when I receive the push notification?

And also I need to vibrate my mobile when receiving the push notification.

Answer (score 9):

For More Information refer this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Add permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
```

**EDIT**

```
// 1. Get a reference to the NotificationManager

    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

// 2. Instantiate the Notification

    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

// 3. Define the Notification's expanded message and Intent

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
    CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

// 4. Pass the Notification to the NotificationManager

    private static final int HELLO_ID = 1;
    mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);


// ----------------------
//        Add Sound
// ----------------------
// a. Default sound

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

// b. Custom sound from SD card

    notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/SOUND.mp3");


// ----------------------
//     Add Vibration
// ----------------------
// a. Default vibration

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

// b. Custom vibration

    long[] vibrate = {0,100,200,300};
    notification.vibrate = vibrate;

// ------------------------
//   Add Flashing Lights
// ------------------------
// a. Default lights

    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

// b. Custom lights

    notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
    notification.ledOnMS = 300;
    notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder     = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                                                    .setSmallIcon(icon)
                                                    .setContentTitle(title)
                                                    .setContentText(message)
                                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);


    Intent              notificationIntent  = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);



    /* Set intent so it does not start a new activity */
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    /* Even if the mode is set to "Sound & Vibration" in the phone, 
     * the status code that getRingerMode() returns is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.
     */
    switch (am.getRingerMode()) 
    {
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            break;
        default:
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
     }


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(intent);        
    notificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

please Add this code in set Notification method

```
         notification.flags   |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
```

refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html)